# How can I use ORM to realize the `one-to-many` table?

Tags: django, django-models

The Account table to RunningLog table is `one-to-one`. 
So, in the Account Model, the foreignKey do not work for this situation, alright?

```
# the user's account
class Account(models.Model):

    balance = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    runningLog = models.ForeignKey(to='RunningLog')  # here only can do one-to-one

# account running logs
class RunningLog(models.Model):

    from_account = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    to_account = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How can I use ORM to realize the `one-to-many` situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current model relation isn't `one-to-one`, but `many-to-one`. There can be multiple `Accounts` with the same `RunningLog`. [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/):

> To define a many-to-one relationship, use `ForeignKey`:

In order to get your desired `one-to-many` relation you need add the `ForeignKey` field to the `RunningLog` model instead:

```
class RunningLog(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(to=Account)
```

Answer (score 0):

The runningLog relation is not one-to-one, but Many-to-one because one RunningLog instance can have MANY Account instance pointing at it.
If you want to have MANY RunningLog instance linked to one Account, you should put a ForeignKey to Account in the RunningLog class.
You will be able to access all those runninglogs from an account using the:
user_account_instance.runninglog_set.all()